# C# / Wpf - How to update the scrollbar values when its content is resized?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, scrollbar

I use a RadGridView (a GridView from telerik libraries) and I resize the rows height for simulate a zoom.

The issue is that the scrollbar values become wrong after a zoom. I receive the values `ExtentHeight` (total virtual height of my RadGridView) and a `VerticalOffset` (my position), and both are false.

[image: Example]

As I know the individual height of every cells, I can manually calculate the `ExtentHeight`, but not the `VerticalOffset`. And the concern is that I have synchronized my grid with a scrollbar which gives a render of the RadGridView, and it can’t be synchronized with these bad values. The only solution is to scroll all the RadGridView, and the scrollbar will be updated with the new heights of its children.
You can see an example in this video, where I scroll after a zoom, and it’s not working. Then I scroll all the grid (with the down arrow), and it works after.
https://youtu.be/QqvTnYK5A6o

So how my scrollbar can automatically updates the values of its content ? 
The method `scrollBar.UpdateLayout();` doesn't work unfortunaly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the property `EnableRowVirtualization` of the RadGridView to false, but it causes a big performance problem unfortunately.